# CircleCI job approve doesn't execute the job

Tags: continuous-integration, circleci

I have following workflow setup in CircleCI configuration:

```
// <<< definition of unit_tests, integration_tests and deploy jobs >>>

workflows:
  version: 2
  build-test-and-deploy:
    jobs:
      - unit_tests
      - integration_tests:
          requires:
            - unit_tests
      - build_images:
          requires:
            - integration_tests
          filters:
            branches:
              only:
                - production
      - deploy:
          type: approval
          requires:
            - build_images
          filters:
            branches:
              only:
                - production
```

The goal is to halt the workflow execution until deploy to production is manually approved. When the workflow execution is fired, it correctly halts before deploy job but after Approve is clicked in the UI, deploy job isn't fired and workflow ends with success.

Do you know what is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CircleCI documentation [contains](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/workflows/#holding-a-workflow-for-a-manual-approval) few requirements that such setup has to meet:

> - `approval` is a special job type that is only available to jobs under the `workflow` key
> - The `hold` job must be a unique name not used by any other job.
> - The name of the job to hold is arbitrary - it could be `wait` or `pause`, for example, as long as the job has a `type: approval` key in it. > - All jobs that are to run after a manually approved job must `require:` the name of that job. Refer to the `deploy: job` in the above example.
> - Jobs run in the order defined until the workflow processes a job with the `type: approval` key followed by a job on which it depends.

The config should have one more job, that is not configured above and its only purpose is to halt the execution:

```
// <<< definition of unit_tests, integration_tests and deploy jobs >>>


workflows:
  version: 2
  build-test-and-deploy:
    jobs:
      - unit_tests
      - integration_tests:
          requires:
            - unit_tests
      - build_images:
          requires:
            - integration_tests
          filters:
            branches:
              only:
                - production
      - hold:
          type: approval
          requires:
            - build_images
          filters:
            branches:
              only:
                - production
      - deploy:
          requires:
            - hold
          filters:
            branches:
              only:
                - production
```

The main point is that the jobs have to be configured as sequential (`deploy` job requires `halt` job to be finished).

Comment: This was a major point of confusion for me too: for whatever reason you can't just add `type: approval` to the job requiring approval, but you need to create another blank job with `type: approval` and require that one! Thanks for clearing it up